# Rotational diffusion - why isn't $\hat n(t)=\hat n(0) \; \forall t$?

Tags: diffusion, non-equilibrium, brownian-motion

Consider the rotational Langevin equation in the absence of an external force:
$$\frac{d \hat n(t)}{dt} =\vec{\xi}(t) \times \hat n(t)$$
where $\vec \xi(t)$ is a Gaussian white noise and $\hat n(t) \cdot \hat n(t)=1$. Take the dot product of this equation with $\hat n(0)$ to get:
$$\frac{d\hat n(0)\cdot \hat n(t)}{dt}=\hat n(0)\cdot\left(\vec{\xi}(t) \times \hat n(t)\right)$$
$$=\vec{\xi}(t)\cdot\left( \hat n(t)\times \hat n(0)\right)$$
Now take the average $\langle \ldots \rangle$ over the noise:
$$\frac{d\langle \hat n(0)\cdot \hat n(t) \rangle}{dt}=\langle\vec{\xi}(t)\cdot\left( \hat n(t)\times \hat n(0)\right)\rangle$$
But since $t\gt 0$ we have that $\vec{\xi}(t)$ is independent from $\hat n(0)$ as the present value of the noise cannot effect a past orientation. And also $\vec{\xi}(t)$ is independent of $\hat n(t)$ as the current orientation does not depend on the current value of the noise. Hence:
$$\frac{d\langle \hat n(0)\cdot \hat n(t) \rangle}{dt}=\langle\vec{\xi}(t)\rangle \cdot \langle\left( \hat n(t)\times \hat n(0)\right)\rangle$$
but $\langle \vec \xi(t)\rangle=0$ Thus:
$$\frac{d\langle \hat n(0)\cdot \hat n(t) \rangle}{dt}=0$$
$$\langle \hat n(0)\cdot \hat n(t) \rangle=\langle \hat n(0)\cdot \hat n(0) \rangle=1$$
Which actually implies that $\hat n(t)=\hat n(0)\; \forall t$ - an answer this is clearly wrong and contradicts with other calculations.  That said I cannot see a floor in my reasoning. Thus my question is: What is conceptually wrong with the above calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just remembered I saw an explanation of something similar in "*Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena*" by Zinn-Justin 4th ed pg63. The reason is that in general averages over the noise $\langle\ldots \rangle$ and time derivatives $\frac{d}{dt}$ do not commute i.e. in this case the equality that fails (I did it implicitly in the question) is:
$$\langle \frac{d}{dt} (\hat n(t) \cdot \hat n(0))\rangle\ne\frac{d}{dt} \langle \hat n(t) \cdot \hat n(0)\rangle$$